# Is it possible that importing a function from another file (python) changes the outcome of your code?

Tags: python, import

I imported a function from another python file and it makes my code run 2 times.

Code goes like this

```
n = int(input("\nCombien des disques? \nNombres des disques: "))
display = init(n)
print("\nYour playground looks like this: \n", display)
```

After some lines it goes:

```
from Partie_C import boucle_jeu
```

And this importing makes this code run again:

```
n = int(input("\nCombien des disques? \nNombres des disques: "))
display = init(n)
print("\nYour playground looks like this: \n", display)
```

So you understand... without it it just asks "n" prints the message and it's done (only one time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasonable way what you're describing could happen is if `Partie_C` is importing the file containing `n = ...`, causing a circular import.

A circular import will cause the code to run twice because importing will cause the imported file to be interpreted. If you import `Partie_C`, it will run. If `Partie_C` then imports this code, this code will run as a result of the import.

```
# Code runs here obviously
n = int(input("\nCombien des disques? \nNombres des disques: "))  
display = init(n)
print("\nYour playground looks like this: \n", display)

 # Indirectly imports this file, causing the whole file to be interpreted again, running the above code again
from Partie_C import boucle_jeu
```

To fix this, either put the code in a function instead of being top level, or use an import guard (`if __name__ == "__main__"`). Or better yet, don't have circular imports. Circular imports are generally considered to be a code smell.  Rearrange your code so you don't have two files importing each other.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to include the import guard...
`if __name__ == "__main__": #to avoid circular importing

    n = int(input("\nCombien des disques? \nNombres des disques: "))


    display = init(n)

    print("\nYour playground looks like this: \n", display)`

Ive tried  this but now "n" can't be imported by the other file or used by other functions

Comment: @AugustinComan If you need it to be available on import, put that code in a function, and return `n` (and `display`) from that function. Then call the function where that data is needed. Having `input` run when the file is loaded is poor practice anyways. Really, all code should be tucked away inside a function except when messing around.